# Conversion error If value = "" Then

Tags: excel, vb.net, exception

I'm getting a error I can't quite explain I have a Excel list I want to load into memory, to see if the next row is still a relative row I check if the cell has a value by doing `If value = "" Then` but the value is `1012738` and it gives me a unhandled exception...

[image: Error image]

I can't quite understand why the code is giving a error, the cell value is formatted just like all previous cells that were checked. But here a error is thrown.

Maybe i'm just not seeing it, and someone can explain?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? How is `oSheet` and `i` defined?

Comment: Might want to look at using `If IsEmpty(oSheet.Range("A" + i).Value) = True` instead of `value = ""` but still post the rest of your code regardless.

Comment: `Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid` - The error explains it all. You're trying to compare an empty string against a number.

Comment: I understand but the exception is not thrown in the previous 6 values and they are also numbers... same number of digits only different combination.

Comment: That would not compile (and thus not happen) with Option Strict On.  Since individual cells could be a different type than the column, you should take extra care in conversions.

Comment: As Plutonix said. Value could be more than just one thing as it returns a `Variant` (Object) [Range.Value Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx). So you do have to take care explicitly the conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the value each time.

```
Dim o As Object = oSheet.Range(xxx).Value

If (o IsNot Nothing) Then
  Select Case o.GetType
    Case GetType(Double)
      ' do work here
    Case GetType(Integer)
      ' do work here

  ...

  End Select
Else
  ...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image isn't showing up for me.

Most exceptions in excel are datatype related.  Most likely, you either have a NULL or a string that looks like an integer to the human eye.  You can blindly try using trim(), int() or str() etc as needed to make sure you're actually testing an integer or matching a string if thats what you are about or you can test them in a programmatic method.

First, the programmatic method of testing ... isEmpty or isNull are needed to ensure the cell is good ...

```
if isEmpty(value) Then
    <do something>
```

This will most likely catch the error which is causing the message. If empty is failing, try testing with isNull.  One means the cell is empty, the other means that it wasn't initialize (rarely an issue in excel, but if using vba code it can happen).

Also ... your if statement is setup in a less than optimal... used <> in place of if  then  + else  ...

Your code ...

```
If value = "" Then
```

General formula when you want to test that something is not something else, use the not equals ...

```
if value <> "value" Then
   "some operation"
```